# JUnit testing package private class in Maven formatted project

Tags: java, junit

I have a package private implementation of an Interface, the methods defined in that Interface can be accessed through a public factory. I was just wondering, how should I unit test that class as it cannot be accessed outside the package, or should I be testing it through the factory?

Thanks

-Abidi

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The usual convention is to put the unit test of a class in the same package as the class under test. This allows the unit test to access package-private and protected methods of the class, and thus to test them.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If I do that, Would "maven test"  execute tests from src directory?

Comment: Putting them in the same package doesn't mean putting them in the same source directory. Just have the same tree of packages (and thus directories) in your main/src/java directory and in your test/src/java directory.

Comment: @JB Nizet, Thanks for this answer. I was stumbling on this as Guice manual asked for package private and I was wondering how to test those classes.